# Implementing a Monitoring "app" in Excel

Tags: .net, vba, excel, ms-office, monitoring

I need to implement a simple monitoring app in Excel. It is for monitoring a small team of around 15 people. The leader has a "central" excel file in which he can browse the progress of each team member and the team as a whole, while each team member has their own Excel doc in which they report their personal progress and it gets "synced" to the leader's document.

I had this implemented as a PHP web app, but I need to implement it using Excel, and I don't have much experience with Microsoft products. What I really have no idea about is how to sync everything. Is there a simple Microsoft server that has an API that allows this?

Perhaps Excel is not the right choice, if so, what other Microsoft product would you recommend?

Comment: Excel was made to sum columns of numbers... are you confident that using it as a front end to some productivity software is _really_ a great idea?

Comment: Not sure about that. I'm completely open to suggestion. I just have to do it in Microsoft products, and a product like Excel that everyone is very familiar with looks appealing to the team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a domain, it's actually not that difficult.

Create one workbook (that's a separate .xls) file for each team member. Protect the workbook with a password so it cannot be easily edited. Then, for each team member's workbook, grant the corresponding team member permission to edit appropriate ranges.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/help-secure-and-protect-data-in-excel-RZ001123531.aspx?section=15

Now, create a workbook for yourself and create formulas which query each team member's workbook (called "external references") and build a summary.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-HP010102338.aspx

There you go... relatively quick to setup, nice consistent interface which isn't too easy for team members to mess up and fairly simple to query.

This is not going to be a perfect solution and will cause some headaches, but that's the tradeoff, right?

Answer (score 2):

1. Can it be done in Excel?  -  Yes
2. How?                      -  Using a shared Excel File
3. Is it recommended?        -  No
4. Alternatives              - If you want to do it from Excel then use Excel as Front End and Access as Back End. Else create everything in Access.

Sharing Excel file has always been frowned upon. It is considered the fastest way to corrupt your file and hence it is never recommended.

Now looking at the alternative.

If you want to do it in Excel then you can design a common input Excel File which you will distribute to your team. And when they update by say clicking an "Update" Button then the data is updated in the `Common Access Database` which is stored in a shared drive. This data, you can pull it by again say pressing a button in the master workbook.

Like I mentioned above you can also choose to create everything in Access. If you want that as an option then you will have to wait for Access Experts to help you with that :)

If it is a complex Day to Day App that you are looking for then you can also go in for Visual Studio which can use VB.Net/C# etc as a Front End and Access/SQL/MySQL/Oracle etc at the Back End.